# jquery on() change on textbox not working using jQ 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery 1.8.3 so trying to change from using .live() to the .on()
Like many others on SO - cant get it worrking  - what am i doing wrong? If its so wrong to use .live()
why does it work so consistently well!

( txtbxhost is a textbox NOT added dynamically its already in the DOM )

```
$('#txtbxhost').live('input', function() {
  // works everytime            
});


$('#txtbxhost').on('change', 'input',  function() {
   // fails everytime           
});
```

and

```
$('#txtbxhost').on('change', '#txtbxhost',  function() {
   // fails everytime           
});
```

and

```
$(document).on('change', '#txtbxhost',  function() {
   // fails everytime           
});
```

i'm out of ideas here ... help ...

Comment: is `#txtbxhost` the actual input?

Comment: Why are you using `.live` at all if the element already exists?

Comment: Mike Brant yes it is the input - @Felix Kling im migrating the script as it was written i know .live() is not good to use hence moving to .on()

Comment: You only need event delegation if the you add the element dynamically. But you said the element already exists. So you don't have to use event delegation and try to convert the `.live` version to the equivalent `.on` version. Just bind the handler directly to the element with `.on`. The documentation has a lot of information and examples: http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want:

```
$(document).on('input', '#txtbxhost',  function() {
   // code here           
});
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UbecU/)

Also, `change` works only when you `blur` - In other words click elsewhere after you change text in the texbox.

So, this should work too

```
$(document).on('change', '#txtbxhost',  function() {
   // fails everytime           
});
```

Check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UbecU/1/)

Comment: works great!! the first code example is better as it must work while focus is in the input box - much thanks appreciated

Comment: @user962902: So, you basically already got it in your last try, but using `change` instead of `input`. Why did you even change the event?

Comment: @FelixKling  - my last attempt didn't work - as stated by karthikr - it only works like on blur() when focus moves away from the subject - if i understand what your asking me then the problem was my knowledge of the arguments(and the order) in .on()

Comment: @user962902: No, I was just wondering why used `change` instead of `input`, since you use `input` in your `.live` code. You already had the correct `.on` call, but changed the event name. Using `input` just seems so obvious with this in mind. Anyways, you got a working solution now :)

Comment: One thing I would note on this solution is that it is generally best to use the closest ancestor to the element you are wanting to run the callback against that exists at page load rather than `document`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how `on()` differs in behavior to `live()`.

There are really two main approaches to using `on()`.  If the element you are interested in exists on the page at load, you can consider directly binding the event like this:

```
$('#txtbxhost').on('input', function () {
    // some function
});
```

This would work in much the same way as `change()` would.

If the element may not exist at page load then you need to work with delegated events.  To do this, you must attach the `on()` to an element that does exist at page load.  This can be `document` or would typically be the closest ancestor to the element the you are interested in that exists on page load.  This delegation works by looking at the event bubbling up the DOM element stack to the element to which you bind `on()`, you then look for a selector within that element to apply the callback to. This looks like this:

```
$('#some_static_ancestor').on('input', '#txtbxhost', function () {
    // some function
});
```

Comment: i'm getting to grips with the difference now - thanks to the brill feedback from u guys. I guess i was using .live() as a catch-all as it seemed to keep working no matter what. Your explanation has just cleared up this point - cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#txtbxhost').on('input', function() {
       // do stuff   
    });
});
```

That should do it.

In your case you don't really need to use .on(), it's main purpose is to deal with dynamically created elements.

Comment: He said it was NOT dynamically added.

Comment: Noticed that and hence deleted my comment.

Comment: *"In your case you don't really need to use .on(), it's main purpose is to deal with dynamically created elements."* Actually no. `.on` unifies all the different event binding method that existed previously (mainly `.live`/`.delegate` and `.bind`). It is equally used for both, normal event binding and event delegation. *Every* event binding method calls `.on` internally.